# What can i do to recover my Galaxy note 1

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note

hallo i tried updating my Galaxy note GT-N7000 and it went on well. latteron it asked me to install another plugin, which i just clicked and it started automatically. now it jst went off and does not come on. when i put it on Charge, it does not indicate and when i remove it from Charge after a while, it jst indicates 100% full and stays off. i have tried all means to put it on and also through recovery mode to no avail. i just really wish someone could help me out in this. Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Reflash it with PC using UniFlash
Visit here: http://www.addictivetips.com/android/uniflash-for-android/

There are also many solutions available on google for reflashing without turning on the device or with a PC.

And if this is due to hardware problem likebif the display is gone, then you should think about going to the care.

Comment: ok thanks alot for ur assistance. il try doing it now

Comment: Best of luck and be carefull dont hard brick it